# Create a Table/Query with JPA/Hibernate in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

So I have Play Framework running at the moment with **JPA** and **Hibernate**. I'm completely new to both and the tutorials I've found around the web are above my head.

**How in the world can I send a simple query or create a table?** This is example code I've written up and I get: `"RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try wrapping this call in JPA.withTransaction, or ensure that the HTTP context is setup on this thread."`

```
    package controllers;


import play.Logger;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import play.db.jpa.JPA;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.db.*;

public class Database {

    public static void initbuild() {
        Logger.info("Checking database structure. The database will be restructured if not in the correct format.");
        JPA.em().createQuery("create table test");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Le'ts start saying that you don't want to build the tables by yourself, just write your models  under the models package annotating them by @Entity and the JPA plugin will automagically generate the tables matching the models that you have defined.
As for the error the error is raised cause you should annotate the method with the @Transactional annotation. 
As stated in the official doc http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJPA 
"Every JPA call must be done in a transaction so, to enable JPA for a particular action, annotate it with @play.db.jpa.Transactional. This will compose your action method with a JPA Action that manages the transaction for you"
Hope it helped btw reading the doc and have a look to the computer-jpa example is suggested